# Oracle trigger updating table in another server

Tags: oracle, triggers

Let's suppose I'm using two oracle servers, A server and B server, but they are located different nations.
They have same schema, called a-bay, and table, called user_data.
Finally, they have same table rows because they want their customers to be able to use both site.

So, I want to use "trigger" for updating data in A server when customers change their personal information in B server, vice versa.

What should I do?
If I am using mysql, I could use federated engine but I can't use in this case.

Moreover, my servers don't support GOLDEN GATE!

Comment: How do you want to connect the 2 servers if you dont want to you DBLINK?

Comment: Did you mean I must use DBLINK to set "trigger" to update another table or Using DBLINK just make easier to use trigger?

Comment: You said you want to connect to 2 servers ? how do you want to that beside DBlink ?. If you want to use dblink I can help you.

Comment: CREATE DATABASE LINK other_db CONNECT TO scott IDENTIFIED BY tiger USING 'tns_alias';

CREATE TRIGGER modify_remote_my_table BEFORE INSERT ON my_table BEGIN INSERT INTO my_table@other_db VALUES(:new.colA, :new.colB); END; /

Comment: give me some minutes Ill right it for you.